# Grails not reloading in test environment

Tags: grails, guard, reloading

I'm testing my app in the interactive console, which I access by 'grails-debug test'.

Then I run my integration tests 'test-app integration:' which goes fine.

But when I change any of my controllers that are being tested, the change does not take effect in my tests results, and I have to quit interactive mode and access it again.

How can I make my tests reload my controllers?

P.D.: My question is much motivated by Grails Guard plugin, which indicates in its usage seccion:

'Ensure that the spring reloading agent is active for test-app (it is NOT by default for test-app, only run-app).'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add -reloading to your grails call as the first parameter.

Comment: Do you know why isn't reloading a default in test environment but it is on dev environment?

Comment: No sorry I'm not really sure.

Comment: This is the default for Grails, only dev environment reloads by default.

Answer (score 2):

After trying the solution proposed by Jeff Beck, I would like to share some examples to clarify:

```
grails -reloading -> reload
grails -> reload
grails-debug -reloading -> reload
grails-debug -reloading test -> reload
grails-debug test -> no reload
grails-debug test -reloading -> no reload
```

I tested this by adding and commenting an exception first in 1 of my controllers and then in 1 of my domain classes, and the reload worked on both.